# Why is the external git repository not an option in Deployment center in azure portal?

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-web-app-service, azureportal, azure-appservice

I created an `app service` in `azure portal` and wanted to configure the `ci/cd` with an external git repository. In the documentation it was mentioned that there is an option to use external git repository but i'm not able to find this in my case. I tried to create the `app service` exactly as mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/azure-apps/azure-continuous-deployment?view=aspnetcore-3.1):

[image]

This how i see the deployment center in azure portal:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We got it working - posting my answer here incase anybody else faces such a situation. I had to create the `service app` using the `windows OS`. It seems that with `Linux OS` there will be only the FTP options enabled (by default) in the deployment center.
After creating the `service app` using `windows OS` it worked fine and i was able to see all options in deployment center wihtout any further configruations.

[image]

Here the statement from Microsoft:

**Use unsupported repos**

For **`Windows`** apps, you can manually configure continuous deployment from a cloud Git or Mercurial repository that the portal doesn't directly support, such as GitLab. You do it by choosing the External box in the **Deployment Center** page. For more information, see Set up continuous deployment using manual steps.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-continuous-deployment

Answer (score 0):

This is not a reasonable appearance, even if the OS type of the web app is Linux, there will be the `External Repository` option.

I think you could try to create a new web app, refer to my steps.

Navigate to App service in the portal -> Add -> Web App -> Create
After creating the web app, check the Deployment Center and configure it.

[image]

Note: The MS official documentation of Continuous deployment has been already changed from `Deployment options` to `Deployment Center`, it is worth a try.

If you still have any problem, I recommend you to contact [Azure Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) for help.

Comment: Thanks Joey, i tested your suggestion but unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: You can try to recreate  a service plan or contact Azure support for help.

Comment: It worked, i'm posting my answer here. Actually linux OS does effect so i can't consider your answer as correct because it is miss-leading (even if the OS type of the web app is Linux, there will be the External Repository option)  - using linux it didn't work at all